# RegExp array of string

Tags: javascript, regex

Good day, not so good in RegEx may be some one could help me.

I've got `array = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", " 1/2" "];`

How I could with RegEx convert to `array = ["5/8", "3/4", "1", "1/2"];`

Value in array could be different.

Comment: You cannot have `5/8` or other fraction values without string representation like `"5/8"`

Comment: Sorry I missed strings ))) edit my question.

Comment: I have also added a answer

Comment: Damn... the question is totally different now... Please proof read before posting next time.

Comment: You all try to use this array = ["5/8", "3/4", "1", "1/2"],

But I whatn to use this one array = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", "1/2""];

Comment: the array you are showing is invalid, there is an error with the last value, because you have more double quotes than expected, so one of them is not beign closed. Also, you should explain better your desired output and input, because there's a lot of answers and for all of them you refuses saying something different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `item.replace(/[a-z]|[A-Z]| /g, '')` and `map()` to get that output array. `item.replace(/[a-z]|[A-Z]| /g, '')` will replace all the alphabets to blank and you will get the desired output.

```js
var array = ["5/8 po","1px"," 1.2","px 1", "px-1", "i-1/2"];
var res = array.map(item => item.replace(/[a-z]|[A-Z]| /g, ''));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could you please say why we need to use item.split()[0] <== zero ?

And please help me with the next in my questions I've got array with " 1/2" ".

Comment: because split will split the values into two part with the regex `/\s+/g` which is `5/8`  and `po` so we need the first value of that array so we use`split()[0] `

Comment: @DevFromEarth I have also updated the answer with more description

Comment: Yeap, but in my troble we could have something like ["5/8 po","1px"," 1.2" ","px 1", "px-1", "i-1/2"];

Comment: @DevFromEarth glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet:

```js
var regex = /(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)(?:\/[1-9][0-9]*)?/g;

var array = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", "1/2"];

var arrayNumbers = array.map(x => x.match(regex)[0]);

console.log(arrayNumbers);
```

Comment: You all try to use this array = ["5/8", "3/4", "1", "1/2"], But I want to use this one array = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", " 1/2" "];

Comment: Yes, i just update the snippet to return the first match :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. This regex tests for fractions or whole numbers:

```js
let arr = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", "1/2"];

const regex = /[0-9]+\/?[0-9]*/;

arr = arr.map(i => i.match(regex)[0]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You all try to use this array = ["5/8", "3/4", "1", "1/2"], But I want to use this one array = ["5/8 po", "3/4 ts", "1 px", " 1/2" "];

Comment: So, your original array? Then you don't need the regex